# error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `max_encoded_len` found for struct `Vec<u8>` in the current scope

Tags: rust, substrate

I'm a newbie in Rust and Substrate. Currently, I'm building a basic chain with Substrate and I have faced with this problem. It says that:

```
error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `max_encoded_len` found for struct `std::vec::Vec<u8>` in the current scope
   --> pallets/account/src/lib.rs:116:14
    |
116 |         Pass4user: VecPass, 
    |                    ^^^^^^^ function or associated item not found in `std::vec::Vec<u8>`
```

And this is my code caused the problem:

```
type VecPass = Vec<u8>;

#[derive(Encode, Decode, Clone, Eq, PartialEq, RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo, MaxEncodedLen)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(Serialize, Deserialize))]
pub struct Account<AccountId> {
    id: AccountId,
    role: Role,
    status: RoleStatus,
    bossID: u8,
    departmentID: Department,
    pass4user: VecPass, 
    subjectID: Subject,
}
```

I tried to include #[pallet::without_storage_info] in my file like a solution on Stackoverflow like this. But it doesn't work.

```
#[pallet::pallet]
#[pallet::generate_store(pub(super) trait Store)]
#[pallet::without_storage_info]
pub struct Pallet<T>(_);
```

My substrate node template use polkadot ver 0.9.26

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

If you guys want to see full content of the file, this is the link for it: https://github.com/DuyUIT2k/Scorechain.git

Comment: It would be helpful if you can put the more detailed actual error

Comment: @SudipGhimire Thanks for your contribution, I have edited my question again. I hope it looks pretty clear

Comment: Substrate in itself is really dependent and incosistent between version and stuff. can you share the whole project if it is ok or I was asking about the whole error message you are getting

Comment: Replace `Vec<u8>` with `[u8; 20]`